# Elegant way to count the number of files in Zip archive

Tags: java, file-handling

I need to count the number of files in several zip archives for error checking.  I've found several answers on SO but nothing elegant.  I currently have the following code which works but it's not pretty:

```
File[] fileListing = new File("ZipFiles").listFiles();
int numberOfFilesInAllZipArchives = 0;
for(File file : fileListing)
{
    ZipFile zf = new ZipFile(file.getName());
    numberOfFilesInAllZipArchives += zf.size();
    zf.close();
}
```

Is there any way to get around creating an object for each zip file or making this process more streamlined?

Thanks!

Comment: Given the structure of a Zip archive it doesn't get a whole lot prettier; the only thing faster is to examine the "Central Directory" byte for byte and that tends to be something Java makes intentionally difficult.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of.  Is there another language that is better for things (file manipulation) like this?

Comment: There is nothing inelegant in the use of objects; or more specifically, if you think there is, then Java definitely isn't the language for you. Maybe you still think using `new` is a slow, expensive thing to do - that was true in the nineties, but isn't anymore. These days it usually amounts to incrementing a memory reference somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing I see inelegant about your implementation is intertwining the file listing work, the zip file opening/closing work, and the counting work. (Do you have another issue with it?)

**Solution 1:** Use Java's try-with-resources block to automate the file closing work thanks to ZipFile being AutoCloseable:

```
...
try (ZipFile zf = new ZipFile(file) {
  numberOfFilesInAllZipArchives += zf.size();
}
...
```

**Solution 2:** In Groovy, separate out the file listing work (and add filename filtering):

```
import java.util.zip.ZipFile

def dir = new File('Downloads')
def num = 0
dir.eachFileMatch(~/.*\.zip/) { f ->
    def z = new ZipFile(f)
    num += z.size()
    z.close()
}
println num
```

**Solution 3:** Also separate ZipFile open/closing work using Groovy's "with" idiom, adding a `zipFileWith(closure)` method to the class `File`:

```
import java.util.zip.ZipFile

File.metaClass.zipFileWith = { closure ->
    def zf = new ZipFile(delegate)
    try {
        closure(zf)
    } finally {
        zf?.close()
    }
}

def dir = new File('Downloads')
def num = 0
dir.eachFileMatch(~/.*\.zip/) { file ->
    file.zipFileWith { zf -> num += zf.size() }
}
println num
```

**Solution 4:** Add an `eachZipFile(closure)` method to the class `File`:

```
import java.util.zip.ZipFile

File.metaClass.eachZipFile = { closure ->
    delegate.eachFileMatch(~/.*\.zip/) { file ->
        def zf = new ZipFile(file)
        try {
            closure(zf)
        } finally {
            zf?.close()
        }
    }
}

def dir = new File('Downloads')
def num = 0
dir.eachZipFile { zf -> num += zf.size() }
println num
```

Comment: Excellent Answer.  #1 is more elegant than what I have.